# Fetch associations on create or save with Sequelize

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sequelize.js, angularjs-resource

Fairly simple problem, just cant find the good/clean way to do this without making a call to another find

I've got my node app rigged up with Angular-Resource, and I'm just making some round-trip like data calls on new or changed data.

So ngResource making the `$save()` call to my `/api/users/:id` and such. And Node reacts to this call by creating or finding the user, making the updates, and saving them.

Whether through `create()` or `save()`, it returns the created record, and for right now, I use `res.json(user)` to spill the created/returned record for my Angular to handle populating my view with the updated information

Now, I know with Sequelizes `find()` and `findAll()` methods, I can use `findAll({ include: [{ all: true }]})` or specify my models individually.

What I want to know is, what is the best way to get my records associations on save/create

and unfortunately, this just doesn't work:

```
models.User.create(newuser, {include:[{ all: true }]}).then(function(user) {
        res.json(user);
    });
```

Do I really have to perform *another* `find()` just to get my managed models associations?

Comment: If you're creating a new object, wouldn't its associations be empty anyway? And, for existing objects, are you using `findOrCreate()`? If so, I believe you could supply the `include` in the first argument. Not sure if that's possible if you're using `upsert()`.

Comment: @st.never Nope, on creation of our users for example, we need to associate them with a group. On the creation, im already providing the information it needs to do this, but it just wont fetch.  In the meantime i've opted to use the `.reload()` method with the include all parameter, and that works, it just sucks it's another sql call yknow?

Answer (score 2):

To better illustrate the opted solution from [RedactedProfile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/817792/redactedprofile)'s comment, here's the code.

```js
models.User
  .create(newuser, {include:[{ all: true }]})
  .then(user => {
      user.reload().then(user => { res.json(user); })
  });
```